# Google index showing Wordpress default favicon instead of set favicon

Tags: wordpress, search, favicon

I am at a complete loss over this one.  I have built this website:

https://www.everyguy.co.nz/

If you go to that site, you will quite clearly see that the site has it's own custom favicon (a red "EG").

This favicon is a 144x144 pixel .ICO file and has been added into the site  section like so:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.everyguy.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/favicon.ico"/>
```

I also have the following code in the theme's functions.php file:

```
// DISABLE WORDPRESS DEFAULT FAVICON //
add_filter( 'get_site_icon_url', '__return_false' );
```

I have tested the above code by removing the custom favicon and the favicon does, indeed, completely disappear and is not being replaced by Wordpress's default favicon.

HOWEVER, Google absolutely insists on indexing the site with Wordpress's default icon instead of the custom icon!  (Search term: "Everyguy", "Everyguy Hair" or "Everyguy Haircuts").

[image: Screenshot of Google Search Results]

I have tried resubmitted the site's sitemap in Google Search Console and I have also used Google Search Console's URL Inspection tool to submit the site's URL for recrawling.  It has recrawled the site several times over the last week and yet the default Wordpress favicon remains in Google's search results!

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions here?

Comment: Not sure how long you have faced this one but while not a quick solution  this one may just take some time to resolve: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/126546

Answer (score 2):

You icon seems to be correctly retrieved by Google:

```
https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=www.everyguy.co.nz
```

You now need to wait for Google to take your new favicon into account, which can take a few days or even longer.

Comment: Oh, cool!  That's a very useful URL to know about!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google need to crawl your website to get the latest update from your website and store it on google.

For quick update, Go to Google Search console for recrawl your website.

Ask google to recrawl your website : https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/ask-google-to-recrawl

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I did that several times over a period of about a week.  It's finally done it for this site now.  Still having issues with other sites, but yeah, looks like it's mostly just a waiting game.  I would have thought Google would be a bit more into it when people are specifically requesting recrawling and resubmitting sitemaps, etc.  Oh well.

Comment: Yeah. Of Course it is depends on google crawling queue I think. But if you instruct to crawl your correct URL, then it will update as soon as possible.