# My favicon is showing in my browser but not on google

Tags: wordpress, favicon

I have a wordpress website which is showing the favicon on browsers but when searching on google using a mobile device it shows the wordpress icon instead. I tried many ways with no results, this is turning me crazy, any advice?

the website is https://simpleylisto.com

[wordpress icon instead of custom favicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i0R6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be fine, even https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=simpleylisto.com is showing your favicon.
  But if your problem is still automatically not solved, then try re-crawling the page.

Comment: I did the re-crawling but still when searching using a mobile device, it shows the wordpress favicon instead of my favicon.  Picture of reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i0R6.png

Comment: [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910014/google-index-showing-wordpress-default-favicon-instead-of-set-favicon#65916886), it will take few days or longer but Google will show up the favicon as it is shown [here](https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=simpleylisto.com). You can also see this suggestion [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126451/wrong-favicon-displayed-on-googles-mobile-serp/126546#126546).

Comment: Ok, then patience is the answer. Its been more than a month since i noticed the problem, it could be a little more. Thanks @iamabdm

Comment: It seems like you are using a plugin from `99 Robots` which has embedded some favicon files in the site among which most of the file gives an  `Error 404`. Please try to fix the issue, and the other favicon files which are not embedded by the plugin seem to be working fine.

Comment: I will look into it, do you happen to know which plugin might it be?

Comment: It is `HFCM` by 99 Robots, everything is working perfectly but the `Snippet # 4: Favicon`.

Comment: Congratulations, finally the favicon is on Google Search.